# Activity Not Found Exception With Facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login

We are getting following error from our **Production** app using the `Fabric Report`.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.t2s.foodhub/com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://m.facebook.com/... flg=0x40000000 pkg=__ChadronAlwaysEqualString (has extras) }
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
```

There is no implmentation document mentioned to include this in the Manifest file if I am not wrong.

Earlier,I had same kind of issue but it says

`"com.t2s.foodhub/com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" is not found`

So, I have added that in my Manifest file, but am now getting different error. I'm not sure what activities I should add.

Currently my `Manifest` looks like below for the Facebook Login

```
<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/fb_app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding just `<activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" />`